# Multiple sql statments (execute all) with eclipse data tools

Tags: sql, eclipse

I use the Eclipse SQL Editor (Eclipse Data Tool Platform 1.9.0) in STS 2.7.1 based on Eclipse 3.7. (Database is MySQL 5.5)

If I have the SQL Scrapbook (or any other file) and put some SQL DDL statements in it where every single statement is written on a single line ending with `;` (that is the configured delimiter in eclipse) then I can execute all statements together (Execute All Ctrl+Alt+X). That works without problems, eclipse execute each statment as a single statement.

But if i have normal insert statements in the same format (each line/statement ending with `;`) then executing all statements together fails. Eclipse seams to try to handle all the statements in one SQL statement. That fails and MySql report an syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO `folder` (`id`, `businessId`, `status`, `title`, `parent_Folder_fk`) VALUES(1, 1544565486, 'ACTIVE', 'Root', NULL);
INSERT INTO `folder` (`id`, `businessId`, `status`, `title`, `parent_Folder_fk`) VALUES(6, 1802811831392782301, 'ACTIVE', 'Ralphz', 1);
...
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `folder` (`id`, `businessId`, `status`, `title`, `parent_Folder_fk`)' at line 2

I can execute each line separate (Select the line and Excecute Selection Alt+X). So I guess there is no failure in the statements, but something is wrong with splitting the statements.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem and a solution.

Execute all does not separate insert into statements properly along delimiters (works fine with other statements tho), and newer MySQL versions disallow multiple statements in a line, most likely to prevent SQL injections.

I doubt the former can be easily fixed, however there is a [configuration property of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) to allow multiline SQL statements. You just have to add "allowMultiQueries=true" to Data Source Explorer / properties of a data source / Driver Properties / Optional / Additional Properties.

Comment: @Frigo: Does this statement "Execute all does not separate insert into statements properly along delimiters" mean there is a bug in Eclipse Data Tools?  If so, do you know if it has been reported to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

To add more than one row to a `table` you can use this `command`:

```
INSERT INTO `folder` (`id`, `businessId`, `status`, `title`, `parent_Folder_fk`) VALUES(1, 1544565486, 'ACTIVE', 'Root', NULL), (6, 1802811831392782301, 'ACTIVE', 'Ralphz', 1);
```

OR

Load using the `plugin` like explained [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.database.doc/html/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html).

---

To insert in multiple tables please test more two things:

1. Create a `stored procedure` with the multiple `inserts`;
2. Create a `stored procedure` for each `insert` on a `table` and `execute multiple stored procedures`.

Comment: I don't understood if you need the `;` on the `GO` or not.

Comment: `GO` is only accepted by Microsoft Tools as an alternative to the standard delimiter `;`

Comment: Nope, skipping semicolons doesn't work unfortunately. Same error, Eclipse / Zend Studio thinks it is one big SQL statement instead of several.

Comment: @Frigo I've put another solution. Try it please :)

Comment: Yeah that works with one table, but as soon as you need inserts into multiple tables it fails :/